# Postgres preg_match

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a column in my table which is named "dot", type -`varchar`. It always contains 4 digits like "2463" or "1343". I need to show all rows where the first digits are greater than 20 (for example). I thought I could do something like this, but it does not come off.

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(dot, '(\d{1}', 'g')) as firstDigit FROM product WHERE firstDigit > 20
```

Comment: Please limit to one question per post. So, what is the expected result?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM product WHERE dot ~ '^(2[1-9]|[3-9]\d)'` should return the rows that start with the first 2 digits more than `20`.

Comment: SELECT column FROM table WHERE LEN(column) > 4

Comment: For PostgreSQL, you can use length(string) or char_length(string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE substring(dot::string from 0 for 3)::int > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with this,

```
SELECT left(cast(dot as varchar), 2) as dot1 
FROM product 
WHERE dot > '20'
```

Comment: This will retrieve value `1234` (i.e. `> 20`) but the first two digits is less than 20 (i.e. `12`)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have updated the answer. The following query is working,  SELECT dot 
FROM product
WHERE LPAD( dot, 2, '0' )::integer  > 20

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4d06d/2)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    four_digits
WHERE
    substr(dot, 0, 3)::int > 20
```

`substr(dot, 0, 3)` takes only the first two characters, `::int` casts these both chars into an integer value which can be compared with the 20